# Classifying movie reviews as positive or negative using binary crossentropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 2) vs (None, 1)).
```

I am classifying movie reviews as positive or negative using binary crossentropy. So, when I am trying to wrap my keras model with tensorflow estimator, I get the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow as tf
genrator=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
train=genrator.flow_from_directory('data/',class_mode='binary',
                                  batch_size=30,target_size=(128,128))
test=genrator.flow_from_directory('test_data/',class_mode='binary',
                                  batch_size=30,target_size=(128,128))
import os
from PIL import Image
folder_path = 'data/'
extensions = []
for fldr in os.listdir(folder_path):
    sub_folder_path = os.path.join(folder_path, fldr)
    for filee in os.listdir(sub_folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(sub_folder_path, filee)
        print('** Path: {}  **'.format(file_path), end="\r", flush=True)
        im = Image.open(file_path)
        rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
        if filee.split('.')[1] not in extensions:
            extensions.append(filee.split('.')[1])
model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([
#     tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape=(128,128,1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='ELU',input_shape=(128,128,1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'),
])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
             loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(train, steps_per_epoch=len(train), validation_data=test, validation_steps=len(test), epochs=10)
```

Comment: Please remember that you're asking for help on a programming Q&A site, not a general help forum: read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and then explain (1) what you were trying to do (2) what code you implemented to make that happen, (3) what you expected that to do, (4) what it did instead and how that differed from expectation and (5) what you already did in terms of debugging/documentation consultation/code rewriting/etc. As concrete problem with your post: _there is no question_. Which is pretty necessary on a Q&A site =)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11396171/paul-bauriegel it isnt work

Comment: I would try two things. Either change the last layer `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')` or use a different loss function like `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: There is a mismatch between the number of output neurons and the mode you set in the generator (binary means 0-1, not one-hot encoded binary classes).

Comment: Why copying verbatim the text from the dup thread?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a sigmoid function and it's a binary classification problem, your last layer, which is the score of belonging to your positive class (or the logit), should have one node. It probably works with changing two to one like this:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
```

The error says that there are two scores for each prediction, but you gave me just one label (0 or 1) per prediction.